# Regex search string with partial matches allowed

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a search pattern like `^FOO.B.A.R`, and I want to check whether a string matches the full search pattern, *but*, if the string is shorter than the search pattern, it's allowed to match only part of it.

That is:

- If the string is 1 character long, it must match `^F`
- If the string is 2 characters long, it must match `^FO`
- If the string is 3 characters long, it must match `^FOO`
- If the string is 4 characters long, it must match `^FOO.`
- ...
- If the string is 9 or more characters long, it must match `^FOO.B.A.R`

Is there a way to specify this in the regex search pattern, or do I need to detect the length of the string and then build the pattern accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to solve this is to adjust the length of the pattern to match the input string, adding a `$` to assert end-of-string for strings less than the length of the regex. You can then use [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) to test. For example:

```py
regex = r'FOO.B.A.R'

strs = ['F', 'FOO', 'FOX', 'FOOYB', 'FOOYA', 'FOOXBYAZR', 'FOOBBAARRX']

for s in strs:
    pattern = regex[:len(s)] + ('$' if len(s) < len(regex) else '')
    print(f'{s}: {re.match(pattern, s) is not None}')
```

Output:

```
F: True
FOO: True
FOX: False
FOOYB: True
FOOYA: False
FOOXBYAZR: True
FOOBBAARRX: True
```

Comment: This makes sense, although I should have said: strings longer than the pattern should be allowed. In that case, I guess the fix is to use `match` instead of `fullmatch` if `len(s) >= len(regex)`?

Comment: I'll edit my question to make this correction

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 I've edited my answer to allow for that, using `match` and appending an `end-of-line` to the pattern if the string length is less than the regex. You could also add `.*` to the pattern if `len(s) > len(regex)` and still use `fullmatch`, but that would be less efficient as you'd be matching characters that aren't important